# Unprotecting specific columns for user entry in worksheets on which i am running macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have an original protected worksheet (Sheet1) in which i manually unprotected a few columns to allow for user entry.  I have set UserInterFaceOnly:=True so macros work on the protected worksheets, and my macro successfully creates a copy of Sheet1 as a template for the next round of entries (Sheet2). Sheet2 in turn will be duplicated going forward in time.

I expected the protections/unprotections to copy from Sheet1 to Sheet2 because the macros simply cuts and pastes columns from Sheet1 to Sheet2.  Sheet2 ends up protected just fine, but the previously unprotected columns are protected again.

I suspect perhaps the protection is actually a property of the WorkBook itself and the protection I see on the new worksheet is nothing to do with my copying the worksheet content and that maybe there's something i need to do in my 'copy' that carries the protection with it.  But I can't find it.

Comment: Share the code you have